# Switching between mobile webapp version using Ionic Framework and Desktop web app version?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, front-end, responsive-design

I own a web application that make use of Twitter Bootstrap 3.
This eases the design of the mobile version since it brings some responsive features.
However, I would like a really native-mobile aspect for the mobile version, but not a native for the Desktop one.
I searched..and I found **this really promising framework**: [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com)

It seems that this framework is really **only focused on Mobile application** and doesn't fit with any other kind of framework like Bootstrap (not mentioned in the documentation).

Therefore, my questions are:
What should be the strategy to keep a desktop version (not using Ionic but bootstrap 3) and a mobile version using Ionic? Making two distinct UI applications? One that would use Bootstrap and the other Ionic? What about duplications??

Comment: Well bootstrap 3's description is "Sleek, intuitive, and powerful mobile first front-end framework for faster and easier web development." When you say "native" do you mean mobile first web app or do you mean a mobile app?

Comment: @Rig AFAIK, Ionic transform web components into a real native app, using Cordova. Bootstrap just creates a mobile web app.

Comment: I looked into Ionic, you still have to use PhoneGap to convert it into a native mobile app. Then too, PhoneGap is just a 'wrapper', which basically means that it wraps your mobile webapp into native binaries, but it still runs like a webapp of sorts. Do you want a complete native experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered creating your backend as an API?

This way you can focus on building any type of frontend (using Ionic or bootstrap or whatever requirements you have) without worrying what happens to the backend if changes are made.

Comment: My backend is an API: A Separated Play 2.2 project, RESTFUL and returning JSON

Comment: Your frontend choices are therefore unlimited now. You could even build native apps themselves.

Comment: Yes, but even if I make a native app, I couldn't force user to use it instead of the standard mobile app. (admitting that I wouldn't spend time for responsive design of my desktop app, since I would write the native)

Comment: What do you mean "I couldn't force user" ? If the only place to get the mobile version is the app store, that is where they'll get it, unless they prefer the browser on their smartphone, which will give you 3 options then.

Comment: Indeed, the worst option would be the third: open a browser and typing the app's url, bypassing the app store.

Comment: There isn't much wrong with using a mobile site. Unless you need to use phone-based functionality (like the camera or other hardware), a mobile site will achieve its purpose.

Comment: Yeah, that was I actually built  (using bootstrap 3 and its responsive mechanism), but the idea to have a look like a real native app is more attractive, IMO.